# Airflow Local Executor Not Running Dags

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I recently just switched my airflow server over from SequentialExecutor to a LocalExecutor. I changed my sql_alchemy_conn from sqlite to an sql database. I initialized the database and changed the executor over. However, none of my dags are running. I need them to run in parallel and they do not run at all. After changing over the config files I reset the scheduler and it says the scheduler is running without issue when i check its status on ubuntu.

[image]

However, the UI says that it does not appear to be running and that new tasks will not be scheduled.[image]